# Sending JSON to Endpoint doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

Idea: I want to call a method which generates an `ArrayList`. As soon as it is ready, I want to redirect this list to an given endpoint.

`class for generating the ArrayList`

```
    @GetMapping("/createcustomer/{start}/{end}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ArrayList<Customer> createCustomer(@PathVariable int start, @PathVariable int end) {
        ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        IntStream.range(start, end).parallel().forEach(index -> {
            customerList.add(generateCustomer());
        });

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String callbackURL = "http://localhost:8080/customerListEndpoint";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        restTemplate.exchange(callbackURL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, ArrayList.class);
        return customerList;
    }
```

`endpoint for receiving the ArrayList`

```
@PostMapping("/customerListEndpoint")
     public void createCustomer(@RequestBody ArrayList<Customer> arrayList) {
        for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
        }
     }
```

`Error:`

```
2018-04-22 16:28:33.203 ERROR 1672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:772) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:725) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:681) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at path.CustomerCreationRestService.createCustomer(CustomerCreationRestService.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: You didn't actually pass the customerList to your call. You can use [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#HttpEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-) HttpEntity constructor

Answer (score 2):

you can send request body along with headers in HTTP entity like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(customerList);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson, headers);
```